# How many clients can connect to an ESP32?

Tags: esp32

I am using an ESP32 as my master and 10 ESP8266-07s are connected to the master that is in AP mode.

But I need at least 12 clients.
Please help me to increase the number of clients the ESP32 can handle in AP mode.

I have read this article but it did not help me
[ESP32 AP max connections: 4 or 10?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54459/esp32-ap-max-connections-4-or-10)

Comment: have you considered ESP-NOW? it can handle more clients and traffic since it has lower overhead than wifi

Comment: esp-now is not secure to me.i think the better way is mesh.but its too force for me right now.so i add aother esp32 in my master and then connect both esp32 by serial to together.and then any of them can conect to 10 client and 1 on the esp32 control and calculate every thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max number of stations for SoftAP is a runtime setting available in Arduino.

ESP32 arduino WiFi library and esp8266 ESP8266WiFi library have it as last parameter in `softAP()` function which starts the SoftAP.

```
bool softAP(const char* ssid, const char* passphrase = NULL, 
    int channel = 1, int ssid_hidden = 0, int max_connection = 4);
```

[esp8266 arduino doc](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/soft-access-point-class.html#softap)

> max_connection - optional parameter to set max simultaneous connected
> stations, from 0 to 8. Defaults to 4. Once the max number has been
> reached, any other station that wants to connect will be forced to
> wait until an already connected station disconnects.

[ESP32 SDK doc](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/network/esp_wifi.html#_CPPv416wifi_ap_config_t)

> uint8_t max_connection   Max number of stations allowed to connect in,
> default 4, max 10

Comment: this code is in the 254 i think,i changed it also.no result!!!

Answer (score 2):

The [SDK API documentation](https://esp-idf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-reference/wifi/esp_wifi.html#_CPPv216wifi_ap_config_t) from Espressif directly notes:

> `uint8_t max_connection`
>
> Max number of stations allowed to connect in, default 4, max 4

**EDIT**

However, another area of the API documentation (The [API Guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-guides/wifi.html#soft-ap-basic-configuration)) notes:

> `max_connection`
>
> Currently, ESP32 Wi-Fi supports up to 10 Wi-Fi connections. If
> max_connection > 10, soft-AP defaults the value to 10.

Comment: strange. I do not believe this. it must be a copy-paste error (from esp8266 doc?). it has two processors

Comment: Perhaps so. I found another place in the API Guide which implies that 10 is the max.

Answer (score -1):

If you use softAP, you can set the max number of connections to 16 I believe.

```
WiFi.softAP(const char* ssid, const char* passphrase, int channel, int ssid_hidden, int max_connection);
```

Comment: i use soft ap ,and realy thiscode,and changed the code  max connection to 16,but didnt worked.is the chanel numer important?

Comment: i should do it,so i must try any idea which everyone suggest me